# How to run C++ code in WebAssembly and capture stdout?

Tags: c++, node.js, webassembly

Give this program em C++

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

How can I compile it to WebAssembly and capture stdout? Would it be possible to limit the use of memory and other resources during execution, like a sandbox, maybe using the `isolated-vm` project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to run the code would be to compile it with Emscripten:

```bash
emcc main.cpp -o main.js -s WASM=1 -s NO_EXIT_RUNTIME=1 -s EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS='["cwrap"]'
```

I am not sure how you want to run it, but you tagged the question with `node.js`, so this is how to run it in node:

```bash
node main.js
```

You can check the [Emscripten documentation](https://emscripten.org/docs/) in order to better understand every flag, but basically the command above compiles the code to wasm (Emscripten is a C to JavaScript compiler at origins).

As for `isolated-vm`, the resulting code is javascript + wasm, so in theory, any method that you use to run javascript code with node should work. The code isn't any different from other javascript code that calls to webassembly.

Comment: This will work and thank you for your answer. Do you have any idea how to use with isolated-vm? I really want to limit the resources.

Comment: Not really, but according to this example https://www.npmjs.com/package/isolated-vm#examples it seems that you can put your code into the `hostile` variable, you just have to read the file on disk

```
const fs = require('fs');
const hostile = fs.readFileSync('main.js', 'utf8');
```

Of course, you don't want to go over the limit, so take care what you place in it.